# Convert query SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to use the SQL Server query below in .NET MVC

```
select *
from table1
where a = 1
and b not in (select fk_b from table2 where c = 1)
```

But I don't know how?

```
entity.table1.Where(record => record.a== 1 && record ....???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LINQ query syntax, the query should be:

```cs
var result = (
    from a in entity.table1
    where a.a == 1
    and  
    !(
        from b in entity.table2
        where b.c == 1
        select b.fk_b
    ).Contains(a.b)
    select a
).ToList();
```

While in method expression,

```cs
var result = entity.table1.Where(record => record.a == 1
    && !entity.table2.Select(y => y.fk_b).Contains(record.b))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Why `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, is it `.AsEnumerable()` not suitable here as it will load the query result for `table2` data into memory? While the sub-query can actually work without `.AsEnumerable()` (the task is done in database side instead in memory) Appreciate if you can give me some advice and correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is exactly my thinking, there is no point loading it into memory when you can do this server-side

Comment: I see. Thanks for the kindly feedback. Appreciated.